# Difference between Channels and Permission.acl in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger composer, If we were able to restrict the visibility of transactions(Visibility of historian records along with CRUD operations on the resources) using permission.acl  in the same channel, do we need to use multiple channels. If they both are different in terms of usage, could you please explain how they differ from each other.

Also if there is single channel and separated the visibility of transactions through permission.acl, how can we restrict events for multiple participants/organizations i.e, fetch events to the owner or specific organization.

Thanks in advance,

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Using one channel all transaction will be committed to all peers on channel even if you restrict accessing / viewing transaction through ACL , so if you need to protect private transaction between a specific peers , so separate those peers on different channel.
for event you can publish different events for the same transaction and for each client make it subscribe to different event.
example transaction (update asset owner ) publish two events ( Event A , Event B)
and for client can choose to subscribe to ( Event A ) only and another client can subscribe to (Event B)

Comment: Thanks @labib-farag , regarding events my question is if all the participants are in the same channel, can we restrict one participant event not sharing/fetching with other participant events. This restriction is to provide security to allow the subscription for only the event owners.

Comment: for publishing event you can restrict event sharing according to current participant using function getCurrentParticipant() , also for fetching event you can make relation with participant in event that will be published and make condition to subscribe to specific participant  example  event TradeNotification {
  --> Commodity commodity
  --> Trader trader 
}    then using the trader identity published in event you can execute some logic while subscribing to events

Answer (score 0):

**Permission Access Control (ACL):** allows to implement different layers of grants on the assets and participants of the business network. The ledger ( data ) are shared between all the peers which joined the channel and the business network.

**Channel:** allows you to "physically" separate the ledger between peers. If a peer doesn't join a channel, it haven't a copy of the data.

The combination of channel and ACL allows to create complex configuration of the access to data.

Regarding the events I think you could implement different events based on the identity of the participant:

```
async function sampleTx(tx) {
    var currentParticipant = getCurrentParticipant();
    let factory = getFactory();

    let eventOne = factory.newEvent('org.example', 'EventOne');
    let eventTwo = factory.newEvent('org.example', 'EventTwo');

    if(currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedType() !== 'org.example.ParticipantOne'){
      //....
      emit(eventOne);

    } else if(currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedType() !== 'org.example.ParticipantTwo'){
      //....
      emit(eventTwo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @leonardo-carraro , for the events can we stop participantTwo to listen eventOne securely.